# How to use a variable plus glob ($var*) in bash

Tags: bash

I'm having a issue with a script.

So this is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date +"%m-%d-%y"`

dokuwiki="dokuwiki.$date*.toolbox.admin.tar.gz"

if test -e  $dokuwiki
then
echo "works"
else
echo "shits broken yo"
fi
```

My problem, I think it doesn't find the file which is weird

files are like this:

```
dokuwiki.09-12-14-06-00.toolbox.admin.tar.gz
```

cheers

Comment: How many files match the wildcard pattern?

Comment: Do you run the script from the directory where the file resides?

Comment: about 5 files and yes. if I do it via grep I can find the file but I dont want to do it via grep

Answer (score 1):

The quotes prevent the * from performing the glob to match the file. If there is only one file that will patch then simply remove the quotes; otherwise you'll have to modify the script to handle multiple filenames in the expansion, e.g.

```
for filename in $dokuwiki; do
    # do something with $filename
done
```

Comment: Have you tested it? The `*` is expanded in the test where there are no quotes. In the assignment, the quotes don't matter.

Comment: When no files are found you will process a filename with an *.
You can loop with `ls ${dokuwiki} 2>/dev/null | while read filename; do ...`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the star (`*`) expansion is done by bash.

with one doku* file

```
mybox $ touch dokuwiki.09-12-14-06-00.toolbox.admin.tar.gz
mybox $ date=`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
mybox $ echo $date
09-12-14
mybox $ dokuwiki="dokuwiki.$date*.toolbox.admin.tar.gz"
mybox $ echo $dokuwiki
dokuwiki.09-12-14-06-00.toolbox.admin.tar.gz
mybox $ test -e $dokuwiki ; echo $?
0
```

with two docu* files

```
mybox $ touch dokuwiki.09-12-14-05-00.toolbox.admin.tar.gz
mybox $ test -e $dokuwiki ; echo $?
-bash: test: dokuwiki.09-12-14-06-00.toolbox.admin.tar.gz: binary operator expected
2
```

the line `test -e doku*`  is expanded into `test -e doku-1 doku2`.

you might wish to use

```
if ls $dokuwiki > /dev/null  2>&1 
then
   ...
```

as test part.

Comment: You can write the testpart as `if [ -n "$(ls $dokuwiki 2>/dev/null)" ]` or `if [ $(ls $dokuwiki 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0 ]`.

Comment: @WalterA your solution are OK, however, `ls` will give a return code that can be used by `if`. TI clarify, I edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the exists in if like this

```
if [ -e $docuwiki ]
then
    echo "works"
else
    echo "broken"
fi
```

it would work.
As mentioned below the if statement is equivalent. Having recopied from the question I think it is actually a problem with the variable docuwiki as I cannot echo that correctly, rewriting it by hand helped.

Comment: test -e foo and  [ -e foo   ] are equivalent.

Comment: you are right, it worked this way round for me, I think I failed the original copying